# Were King Salva and Amba in mutual love before the Swaymvara?

Tags: mahabharata

In Mahabharata tv serials it is being shown that King Salva and Amba knew each other even before the Svaymvara and both were mutually in love . And It was planned by both of them that Amba would choose King Salva in the Svayamvara.

I doubt it is true because it doesn't make any sense . If they were already in mutual love , then why need the Svayamvara ? Was the love only one sided from Amba?

So, My question is it is true that they were in mutual love before the Svayamvara?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the king of Śālva and Amba were in mutual love before the Svayamvara. After Bhishma takes the princesses of Kashi to Hastinapuram, Amba informs Bhishma of the mutual love as follows:-

> मया शाल्वपतिः पूर्वे मनसाभिवृतो वरः। तेन चास्मि वृता पूर्वे रहस्यविदिते पितुः॥६॥
>
> In my mind, the king of Śālva has been chosen by me as a husband, and **I too have been chosen by him** in secret, a fact that is unknown to my father.
> -*Mahabharata Udyoga Parva Chapter 174, verse 6*

As for the reason for svayamvara, it can be seen from the above verse itself that Amba’s father was unaware of the mutual acceptance of the king of Salva and Amba and hence the Svayamvara had been arranged by him.

Comment: Its Amba fault that she taught Salva was great warrior who can defeat bhisma. But look here Amba was Diyu Vasu wife in her previous birth as Vasu goddess.. i.e. Bhisma's wife.. even for devatha sthree they were falling in love with somebody who is not suppossed to be their husband.. what will happen mere humans..